# systemctl throws error when starting PostgreSQL 15 on RockyLinux 8

Tags: postgresql, systemctl

i am trying to upgrade my Database from PGSQL 11 to 15. Installation was a charme as well as the registering as a deamon. But starting the deamon (systemctl) is simply not working. And I cannot understand what the Problem is. Hope you know what the issue is.

Output `systemctl start postgresql-15.service`

```
[root@server /]#  systemctl start postgresql-15.service
Job for postgresql-15.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
```

Output `journalctl -xe`

```
--
-- Unit postgresql-15.service has begun starting up.
Sep 02 03:46:15 server postmaster[146143]: 2023-09-02 03:46:15.254 CEST [146143] LOG:  redirecting log output to logging collector process
Sep 02 03:46:15 server postmaster[146143]: 2023-09-02 03:46:15.254 CEST [146143] HINT:  Future log output will appear in directory "log".
Sep 02 03:46:15 server systemd[1]: postgresql-15.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 02 03:46:15 server systemd[1]: postgresql-15.service: Killing process 146144 (postmaster) with signal SIGKILL.
Sep 02 03:46:15 server systemd[1]: postgresql-15.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- The unit postgresql-15.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 02 03:46:15 server systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL 15 database server.
-- Subject: Unit postgresql-15.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit postgresql-15.service has failed.
--
```

Comment: What does the `Future log output will appear in directory "log".` say?

Comment: Hi, that was a good question and helped me to solve the problem. Since I was sure there is no log, I discorvered, that the log simply is not stored at /var/log/. After digging up the right log file, I found out that 15 is to new for my plesk. Thank you!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Never had any issue upgrading postgresql to the latest other than the pesky reindexing and collation updates each time somebody monkeys with ICU. You may want to reconsider management tools if they are what is holding you back from updates. (depending on how quickly they fix the issue)